# Reusing MVC4 Controller for posting data from a desktop application

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, post, ms-word

I have built an MVC4 web app with MongoDB as the backend.  Some of the data that goes into Mongo originates from a desktop app and is posted via a WCF Service.

Was hoping to dump the WCF Service and just use the MVC4 controllers.
It worked for the Get, but when I tried to Post, it produced an error.

I am certain there is plenty I am not aware of.  I guess the first question is...
is this possible?

---

Thank you MarcusTzaen:  Yes WebAPI is the way to go.  After a bit more testing I know why I was questioning.

From a WPF app the following request is sent (And Works):
    From a WPF app the following request is sent:

```
POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/PostDocument HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx
Content-Length: 116
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{ "id" : "2134", "vals" : { "some" : "value" }, "tia" : { "tsome" : "value" }, "specCond" : { "ssome" : "value" } }
```

The Web method receives the request as follows:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.ActionName("PostDocument")]
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost, System.Web.Mvc.HttpPut]
public Dictionary<string, object> PostDocument(object json)
{
     //do stuff here

      return dict;
}
```

When I do this from Microsoft Word I create the following request:

POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/PostDocument HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json
    Host: xxx.xxx.xxx
    Content-Length: 1223
    Expect: 100-continue

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52b47bf88d1971193090155d"), "clientId" : "14173", "cdi" : "81098", "d" : "144", "dnd" : "12000", "dndi" : "1JB", "specCond" : { }, "vals" : { }, "tia" : { "tiaCount" : 0 } }
```

The difference ended up being the ObjectId, which the PostDocument web method choked on.
Converting the ObjectId to a string solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) ?

You can Specify that an action supports the POST HTTP method by using [HttpPost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httppostattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) .